# Insert data in MySQL from Angular 2 web Application

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, angular

I'm starting to learn Angular 2, and i have to insert some data in a database using Ajax. I created a Angular 2 page to register some TV Series in the data base.

Follow the code of the `form`:

```
<form (submit)="cadastrarSerie()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputNomeSerie">Nome da Serie:</label>
    <input name="inputNomeSerie" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNomeSerie" [(ngModel)]="nome" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputSinopseSerie">Sinopse:</label>
    <textarea name="inputSinopseSerie" class="form-control" rows="5" id="inputSinopseSerie" [(ngModel)]="sinopse" required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputTemporadaSerie">Temporadas:</label>
    <input name="inputTemporadaSerie" min="1" type="number" class="form-control" id="inputTemporadaSerie" [(ngModel)]="temporadas" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="inputProdutoraSerie">Produtora da Serie:</label>
    <input name="inputProdutoraSerie" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputProdutoraSerie" [(ngModel)]="produtora" required>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cadastrar</button>
</form>
```

Follow the code of the function that makes the requisition to a .php file, to insert in database:

```
  public nome:String;
  public sinopse:String;
  public temporadas:number;
  public produtora:String;
  public cadastrado:String;

  public cadastrarSerie(){
    if(this.nome.length>0 && this.sinopse.length>0 && this.temporadas>0 && this.produtora.length>0){
      let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
      req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(req.readyState === 4 && req.status==200){
          let x = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

        }
      }
      req.open("get","/cadastrarSerie.php?nome="+this.nome+"&sinopse="+this.sinopse+"&temporadas="+this.temporadas+"&produtora="+this.produtora,true);
      req.send();
    }
  }
```

And there the code of "cadastrarSerie.php" (registerSerie.php in english) that inserts on db:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['nome']) && isset($_GET["sinopse"]) && isset($_GET["temporadas"]) && isset($_GET["produtora"])){
    include "./Serie.php";
    $serie = new Serie(null,$_GET["nome"],$_GET["sinopse"],$_GET["temporadas"],$_GET["produtora"]) ;
    $serie->inserir();
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
?>
```

I know, the Angular is client-side, although the PHP is server-side, but i don't know how to make it work, i'm using 'ng serve' to start a HTTP server to test the angular 2 page.

How can i insert data on database? I have to use something like Xampp?

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: I think the code is OK, but my .php file isn't opening, i think i have to start some MySQL server or Apache server side by side with the 'ng serve', how can i do that?

Comment: It's better to put the code in the text way rather than in the image.

Comment: I going to edit

Comment: @NathanSchroeder use xampp to run the php code or something similar depending on your OS

Comment: @NaguibIhab I change the line of the "open" to:       req.open("get","http://localhost:8080/T2AV1-Nathan_Tales_PHP/modelo/cadastrarSerie.php); to open with Xampp and i got that error: zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:8080/T2AV1-Nathan_Tales_PHP/modelo/cadastrarSerie.php 0 ()

Comment: You might be trying to run both servers on the same port 8080

Comment: @NaguibIhab No, the 'ng serve' is running in the port 4200.

Comment: Actually upon reading your comment again, that doesn't look like an error it looks like a log

Comment: Open that error i got this message: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the inputs you provided, it seems you need a server to host your .php files,
unless it is served by a web server (xamp/wamp/lamp..etc), it wont work.
you will need to install xampp and then move your php file into its www directory.